# `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Shell` , Prism - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I'm trying to run PRISM (MEF) example project, but get this error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in
>   'Prism4MefDemo.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: The assembly with display name
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Shell' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context
>   of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Shell, Version=3.5.41019.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've tried to remove and manualy add reference to  `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` but still nothing.

The version of this DLL is `3.0.1.0`, and not `3.5.41019.1` as in the Exception.

This is the line with the Excecption:

```
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<ShellWindow>();
    }
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of .net are you using, and are you forcing a specific cpu architecture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after trying everything, I looked for others files in my computer (**Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll**) and found newer version, as expected by the Exception (`3.5.41019.1`) in `MicrosoftRibbon for WPF\V3.5` folder.

It is strang,because the latest version of the **NuGet** package `is 3.0.1`.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sometimes last version of a package in NuGet has lower number because that is the Safe Version NOT a newer Beta version... You can get your ideal package by putting your mentioned version in the end of Install-Package command line...

Answer (score 19):

Finally I solved this issue by installing **Multilingual App Toolkit**  from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e2a913c-709c-44e6-8b90-a552eede1903) and Add Reference to "Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll" from the location **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Multilingual App Toolkit"**  or copy the dll to your private assembly folder and refer it.

When you install **Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll** from Nuget, it was installing v3.0.1, But the actual expected version was v3.5.41019.1. you ll get this new version from the above path.

Thanks

Comment: searched for this a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem when using the Ribbon control.

The solution was remove the `ribbon:` prefix from the very start of the XAML and use the default ribbon control, not the one that utilizes a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll v3.5.41019.1 to your project references, would solve the problem.

Comment: The OP has specifically stated in the question that they have already tried removing and re-adding the reference.